# awk without printing newline

Tags: scripting, awk, newline

I want the variable sum/NR to be printed side-by-side in each iteration. How do we avoid awk from printing newline in each iteration ? In my code a newline is printed by default in each iteration

```
for file in cg_c ep_c is_c tau xhpl
printf "\n $file" >> to-plot.xls
    for f in 2.54 1.60 800 
        awk '{sum+=$3}; END  {print  sum/NR}' ${file}_${f}_v1.xls >> to-plot-p.xls
    done
done
```

I want the output to appear like this

```
cg_c ans1  ans2  ans3  
ep_c ans1  ans2  ans3 
is_c ans1  ans2  ans3
tau  ans1  ans2  ans3 
xhpl ans1  ans2  ans3
```

my current out put is like this

```
**cg_c**
ans1
ans2
ans3
**ep_c**
ans1
ans2
ans3
**is_c**
ans1
ans2
ans3
**tau**
ans1
ans2
ans3
**xhpl**
ans1
ans2
ans3
```

Answer (score 275, accepted):

`awk '{sum+=$3}; END  {printf "%f",sum/NR}' ${file}_${f}_v1.xls >> to-plot-p.xls`

`print` will insert a newline by default. You dont want that to happen, hence use `printf` instead.

Comment: But mind that `printf` interprets `%s` so use `printf "%s" whatever` instead of `printf whatever`.

Comment: `printf "%s",whatever` You forgot the comma. You can also extend with more variables and separate them with a comma.

Answer (score 87):

The ORS (output record separator) variable in AWK defaults to "\n" and is printed after every line.  You can change it to " " in the `BEGIN` section if you want everything printed consecutively.

Comment: You might even want to set it `""` (no space) to have no separation at all.

Comment: Like this: `awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\t"} {sum+=$3}; END  {print  sum/NR}' ${file}_${f}_v1.xls >> to-plot-p.xls`

Comment: Or `ORS="\r"` if you want e.g. to print a counter showing progression.

Answer (score 79):

<sub>I guess many people are entering in this question looking for a way to avoid the new line in `awk`. Thus, I am going to offer a solution to just that, since the answer to the specific context was already solved!</sub>

In `awk`, `print` automatically inserts a `ORS` after printing. `ORS` stands for "output record separator" and defaults to the new line. So whenever you say `print "hi"` awk prints "hi" + new line.

This can be changed in two different ways: using an empty `ORS` or using `printf`.

#### Using an empty `ORS`

```
awk -v ORS= '1' <<< "hello
man"
```

This returns "helloman", all together.

The problem here is that not all awks accept setting an empty `ORS`, so you probably have to set another record separator.

```
awk -v ORS="-" '{print ...}' file
```

For example:

```
awk -v ORS="-" '1' <<< "hello
man"
```

Returns "hello-man-".

#### Using `printf` (preferable)

While `print` attaches `ORS` after the record, `printf` does not. Thus, `printf "hello"` just prints "hello", nothing else.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "hello"; print "bye"}'
hello
bye
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "hello"; printf "bye"}'
hellobye
```

Finally, note that in general this misses a final new line, so that the shell prompt will be in the same line as the last line of the output. To clean this, use `END {print ""}` so a new line will be printed after all the processing.

```
$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s", $0}'
12345$
#    ^ prompt here

$ seq 5 | awk '{printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}'
12345
```

Answer (score 5):

one way

```
awk '/^\*\*/{gsub("*","");printf "\n"$0" ";next}{printf $0" "}' to-plot.xls
```

Comment: Minor note: never use `printf $0`, since `$0` may contain strings like `%F`, etc... Following easily fails (at least with GAWK 3.1.5): `echo "%F"|awk '{printf $0}'`. Use the `printf "%s",$0` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use ORS dynamically like this:

`awk '{ORS="" ; print($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "); ORS="\n"; print($6-=2*$6)}' file_in > file_out`

Comment: Cool, used it to get IP addresses of nodes in one line on Kubernetes cluster. 

`k get nodes -o wide --no-headers | awk '{ORS=" "; print $6 }'`

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option, here is a solution using fedorqui's example:

`seq 5 | perl -ne 'chomp; print "$_ "; END{print "\n"}'`

Explanation:
`chomp` removes the newline
`print "$_ "` prints each line, appending a space
the `END{}` block is used to print a newline

output:  `1 2 3 4 5`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `awk` way without having to `printf` and `END` (assuming your input is less than, say,`500 MB`):

> ```
> seq 199 | 
>
> mawk NF=NF RS='^$' FS='\n' OFS=
> ```

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343
536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646
566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949
596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116
117118119120121122123124125126127128129130131132133134135136
137138139140141142143144145146147148149150151152153154155156
157158159160161162163164165166167168169170171172173174175176
177178179180181182183184185186187188189190191192193194195196
197198199
```

*(reformatted for readability - it's one single line, with `\n` at its end)*

And if you simply wanna place a space in between :

> ```
> seq 19 | 
>
> mawk 'NF && --NF' RS='^$' FS='\n'
> ```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

if you don't mind 1 extra trailing space, then it's even simpler

> ```
> mawk NF=NF RS='^$' FS='\n'
> ```