# Line Break in C# String

Tags: c#, string, .net-core

I'm receiving a random line break in the following C# string and can't identify why the output is on two separate lines.

I've really only tried to define the variable in two different manners. Both produce the same results.

```
string cmdStr = "docker images | grep -E '^prabhasgupte/webmon.*latest' | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'";
Console.Write(cmdStr);
string imageId = commands.Bash(cmdStr);
Console.Write(imageId);
string x = $"docker tag {imageId} scan_target:{imageId}";
Console.Write(x);
```

This is the output I'm receiving:

> docker images | grep -E '^prabhasgupte/webmon.*latest' | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'
>
> 0043699b906f
>
> docker tag 0043699b906f
>
> scan_target:0043699b906f

```
public static string Bash(this string cmd)
{
    var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you attached a debugger to this?  could one of the two strings contain an extraneous line-break?

Comment: You'd probably want to take a closer look at that `Bash()` implementation

Comment: The string that `commands.Bash(...)` returns contains a newline character.

Comment: I am [not able](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BYhjJW) to reproduce when replacing the `commands.Bash()` call with a fixed string.  I imagine its something to do with that implementation.  See what the debugger returns

Comment: `string imageId = commands.Bash(cmdStr) + " some test";`, try that and run it... Does it seperate the `some test`? Or try this `Regex.Replace(commands.Bash(cmdStr), @"\t|\n|\r", "");`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ In that particular instance it does separate the " some test" on a new line but if I attached that to the end of the same function with other commands, it does not. Here is the Bash function:

Comment: `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` trim the end of this; this is the actual root cause of the later issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the reason this is happening is that `imageId` has a line break in it from the bash command. try trimming the result

```
   string imageId = commands.Bash(cmdStr).TrimEnd( '\r', '\n', Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray() );
```

Comment: Sure, it is correct that the newline is from the bash command, but why put on a band-aid in C# when you can solve the problem in the place where it's really originating from (awk)?

Comment: @DanielCrha I believe you can pass `cat` as a command line arg when calling the script, that may actually remove it, haven't tried it myself, but would be interesting.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ cat means "stream pipe" (usually it covers files) so yes, it does "pump" the output in bash as it were.. I am fairly sure it doesn't insert new line characters because it's fairly common to `grep` its result - incidentally I disagree that it is a **repeat of the same question** as you marked .. he is asking **why** the "random" break appeared.. I am (the only one) telling him why the "random break" is there

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your issue might be awk inserting a newline, which is its default behavior. I copied this from an [awk-related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022001/10509640):

> The ORS (output record separator) variable in AWK defaults to "\n" and is printed after every line. You can change it to " " in the BEGIN section if you want everything printed consecutively.