# How to print matched lines in same line?

Tags: awk

With this awk script I can print Nth line after match `Pattern`.

```
awk '/c&&!--c;/Pattern/{c=N}'
```

Now, I'm trying to print the line when matches `Date` and print the 3rd line after matches `Time`

```
echo "x
Date:2/19/2021
a
b
Time:
val:14:31:42
val:15:51:35
val:16:28:03
val:17:04:11
z
w" | 
awk '/Date/{d=$0} 
      c&&!--c;/Time/{print d " - "; c=3}'

Date:2/19/2021
val:16:28:03
```

The script prints what I want but in different line and I'd like to print the output in the same line like this

```
Date:2/19/2021  -  val:16:28:03
```

How can this be done? Thanks in advance

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021982/awk-without-printing-newline

Comment: change to `printf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of print which always adds ORS, use printf instead:

```
echo "x
Date:2/19/2021
a
b
Time:
val:14:31:42
val:15:51:35
val:16:28:03
val:17:04:11
z
w" |  awk '/Date/{d=$0}
      c&&!--c;/Time/{printf d " - "; c=3}'
```

The first parameter passed to printf is the format string.  If the format string contains a percent sign the whole thing will break because printf treats percent signs as special when they occur in the format string.

In your specific case the date will never have a percent sign, but if you use this method for printing other strings without a newline, you need to supply a format string separate from the parameter you are printing:

```
echo "x
Date:2/19/2021
a
b
Time:
val:14:31:42
val:15:51:35
val:16:28:03
val:17:04:11
z
w" |  awk '/Date/{d=$0}
      c&&!--c;/Time/{printf "%s - ", d; c=3}'
```

Comment: There is no need for the `%s`

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm not an expert but I've selected your answer because I see it easier.

Comment: @AvenDesta if you're referring to `printf d` vs `printf "%s", d` - never do `printf whatever` for any user input as it'll fail cryypticall if/when the input contains printf formatting characters like `%s`, always do `printf "%s", whatever` instead.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. I have also used `exit` in case you are using an Input_file to read values from then in that case it will help.

```
your_variable | 
awk ' /^Date:/{val=$0;next} /^val/ && ++count==3{print val" - "$0;exit}'
```

With OP's way try:

```
your_variable | 
awk ' /^Date:/{val=$0;next} /^Time/{found=1;next} found && ++count==3{print val" - "$0;exit}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Is nice, but the 3rd line not always begins with `Val` or 1rst, 2nd, 3rd lines can have different texts. The unvariable string will always be the string `Time` and get the 3rd below of it.

Comment: @GerCas, sure, already(few secs back or so) added your attempted code's improvement in answer, cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

another similar one

```
... | awk '/Date/ {printf "%s - ",$0}
           /Time/ {c=4} 
           c&&!--c'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Why it works even in your code c=4 and not c=3?

Comment: Because I changed the order, it counts the line with Time as well.